# Let ABCD be a trapezium with AD parallel to BC, there is a point M in the interior of the segment BC, AB=AM, DC=DM. Find [AMD]:[ABCD]

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology

Does the phrase 'in the interior of' refer to M being on the line? Because all solutions online to the question have assumed that M is on the line BC like this one:

[image: Solution by https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/let-abcd-be-a-trapezium-with-ad-parallel-to-bc/]

It becomes very easy if we assume M to be on the line but I'm confused by how the question's phrased

Comment: Yes, this is the meaning. And $M$ is different from $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles ABM and DMC must be isoceles, with bases BM and MC respectively. Draw perpendicular lines to the parallel sides through A and D to see, that the quotient of the area of the triangle and the area of the trapezium is one half.

Comment: The OP was asking about something else.

Comment: What else was he asking then? [ABC] sometimes stands for the area of a triangle ABC. Otherwise it is an 'undeclared variable', and the proplem is just not defined. 

Comment: He was asking whether $M$ being in the interior of $BC$ means $M$ being on the segment $BC$ (in which case the OP knew how to solve the problem). Read the title and the body of the question carefully. Read the comments, too.